# Chisel3: Partial assignment to a multi-bit slice of a Vector IO

Tags: chisel

It is possible to make a partial assignment to a vector IO as follows:

```
import chisel3._

class example_1 extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val in1  = Input(Vec(4, Bool())
        val out1 = Output(Vec(4, Bool())
    })
    for (I <- 0 to 3){
        io.out1(I) := io.in1(I)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make a partial assignment to a multi-bit slice of a vector. The following code doesn't work

```
import chisel3._

class example_1 extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
       val in1  = Input(Vec(4, Bool())
       val out1 = Output(Vec(4, Bool())
    })
    for (I <- 0 to 1){
        io.out1((I*2)+2-1, I*2) := io.in1((I*2)+2-1, I*2)
    }
}
```

One would assume that this should be possible using slice, however, whilst slice works for referencing a slice of the io.in1 vector

```
val in1_sl = io.in1.slice(0, 2)
```

It is not possible to use slice on the LHS of the assignment to create a slice of io.out1:

```
io.out1.slice(0, 2) := io.in1.slice(0, 2)
```

The example that I've used here is just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this currently in chisel.  Using slice on the LHS means that the collection returned by splice is not something that supports a connect method.  That being said, the following seems to work, though I haven't considered into all the implications of it.

```
class Slicer extends Module {
  implicit class SeqHelper(val seq: Seq[Bits]) {
    /**
      * Promotes a Seq of Bits to a class that supports the connect operator
      */
    def := (other: Seq[Bits]): Unit = {
      seq.zip(other).foreach { case (a, b) => a := b}
    } 
  }

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in1  = Input(Vec(4, Bool()))
    val out1 = Output(Vec(4, Bool()))
  })

  io.out1.slice(0, 2) := io.in1.slice(0, 2)
}
```

You could put the SlicerHelper in a package object making it generally accessible. Less exotic idioms to consider might be.

```
io.out1.slice(0, 2).zip(io.in1.slice(0, 2)).foreach { case (a, b) => a:= b }
```

or

```
io.out1.zip(io.in1).slice(0, 2).foreach { case (a, b) => a:= b }
```

Comment: Solution 2 of this answer did the trick. I had actually tried using a .slice, .zip & .map combination previously. The reason why it didn't work was that the higher Int specified to a .slice is "until" rather than "to" . Also, the order that the range is specified to a .slice is the reverse of the order that a "range" of a UInt is specified in (low,high) -> (high,low).