# How to express specified index range of a Vec?

Tags: chisel

For example ,I want to express Vec(0),Vec(1),Vec(2),Vec(3),Vec(4) together.Can I express it  Vec(0->4) ?If it's error,what should I do ?
And I also want to know which is the fullest document of the Chisel?I have many problem,but I can't find the answer in my documents.I have Digital Design with Chisel and chisel_cheatsheet.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to express Vec(0),Vec(1),Vec(2),Vec(3),Vec(4) together.Can I
>   express it Vec(0->4) ?If it's error,what should I do ?

I think you are looking for a slicing function for Vec as [plenn08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373902/chisel3-partial-assignment-to-a-multi-bit-slice-of-a-vector-io) asked.
[Chick Markley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380109/4422957) gave a response for a slice assignement.

> I have Digital Design with Chisel and chisel_cheatsheet.

That's a good start. You can also take a look at the [chisel-bootcamp](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp/master) which can be done with a simple [web browser](https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/freechipsproject-chisel-bootcamp-s57mx7nt/notebooks/1_intro_to_scala.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

When you're new to Chisel and Scala it can be a little intimidating, but I would suggest taking a look at the API docs and learning how to read them: https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.2.0/index.html

In this case, for Vec: https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.2.0/chisel3/Vec.html

Vec extends Scala [Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/collection/Seq.html) and thus has a massive assortment of useful methods like `slice` as discussed in the post Fabien linked.